# Explanation for ruby's CSV.foreach enumerator?

Tags: ruby, csv, foreach, enumerator

Ruby's `CSV.foreach('file.csv', headers: true)` returns an enumerator, but I can't seem to call any enumerable methods on it, i.e. I can't call `CSV.foreach('file.csv', headers: true).map(&:to_hash)` or even `CSV.foreach('file.csv', headers: true).to_a`.  This is unexpected behavior, as I can call these methods on other enumerators like `1.upto(5).to_a` etc.  What's the explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the source [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach). At the time of writing, `CSV::foreach` is defined as

```
def self.foreach(path, options = Hash.new, &block)
  open(path, options) do |csv|
    csv.each(&block)
  end
end
```

so the `each` enumerator is enclosed within the `open` block and the method returns `nil`. If you want to interact w/ the enumerator you can do something like

```
CSV.open('file.csv') do |csv|
  csv.each.map do |row|
    # whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like it's returning an enum here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/01b1f004618b67f2e3033e055cb3a87f05fd3fa6/lib/csv.rb#L1119

Comment: Nice, looks like it was added 2 months ago https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/28204c67ed6e55309cdf05e5e20f1f7e59e85e96#diff-cf88b0776379e2c695d51fb040d84c6c

Comment: Part of 2.1 preview, so we should see this improvement soon